# FTP Download of single file failing 550 access denied

Tags: ftp

I am using the Rebex FTP c# library and am attempting to download a single file from a public FTP site. Every other file on this FTP site is able to be downloaded, except for one specific file.

Whenever I try to download the file, I get a 550 Access Denied error.

From Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 504 HTTP-FTP Gateway failed

Content-Length: 606

Fiddler was unable to act as a HTTP-to-FTP gateway for this
response. 

550 Permission denied.
```

I have switched to using System.Net.FtpWebRequest in an attempt to get more information on the error (I know it is not recommended for actual use. I still get the same 550 access denied error on this one specific file. This error is returned consistently any time we try to download the file, not just a once or twice error.

I also get a 550 access denied error when accessing the public site through Windows Explorer, IE, and Chrome.

I have contacted the administrator of the FTP site, and they have claimed there is nothing wrong with their system and that my IP has not been blocked.

We access the system anonymously, as it is a public FTP site. When we access the file from outside my company's network IP (e.g. from a home computer) the file is available for download.

Sometimes when I reboot the server that is running the application that downloads from the FTP site I can download the file in question, but other times a reboot of the server does not fix the problem. I can also run the application on a server that it outside our main network and the file is available for download. It seems that our IP is blocked just for this specific file.

I am looking for leads at this point. The FTP administrators are saying that this is something on our end, but every other file is available for download. Regardless of the time of day, the file in question returns a 550 access denied error, meaning that we're not getting unlucky and trying to download the file while the site has it locked for update.

Edit2: The server has been rebooted and the file is downloading successfully as of now.  Here is a log file from a successful download using Rebex.Net:

```
2019-08-20 08:23:29.143 Opening log file.
2019-08-20 08:23:29.688 INFO Ftp(1) Info: Connecting to pubftp.spp.org:21 using Ftp 3.0.4086.0.
2019-08-20 08:23:29.689 INFO Ftp(1) Info: Using proxy none.
2019-08-20 08:23:29.884 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Connection succeeded.
2019-08-20 08:23:29.939 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 220-This system is restricted solely to <clip>...
2019-08-20 08:23:29.939 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 220-
2019-08-20 08:23:29.939 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 220 Use anonymous as user and email address as password.
2019-08-20 08:23:30.682 INFO Ftp(1) Command: USER anonymous
2019-08-20 08:23:30.733 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 331 Password required for anonymous.
2019-08-20 08:23:30.734 INFO Ftp(1) Command: PASS ************
2019-08-20 08:23:30.787 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 230 Login OK. Proceed.
2019-08-20 08:23:30.788 INFO Ftp(1) Command: FEAT
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 211-Features supported:
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  COMB target;source_list
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  REST STREAM
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  SIZE
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  MDTM
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  MFMT
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  XCRC filename;start;end
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  SSCN
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  MLST Size*;Modify*;Create;Type*;Unique;Perm*;Lang;Media-Type;CharSet;
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  MODE Z 
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  XNOP 
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  UTF8
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  UTF-8
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  LANG EN*
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response:  CLNT
2019-08-20 08:23:30.838 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 211 END
2019-08-20 08:23:30.841 INFO Ftp(1) Command: SYST
2019-08-20 08:23:30.892 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2019-08-20 08:23:30.892 INFO Ftp(1) Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2019-08-20 08:23:30.942 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 200 Entering UTF-8 mode.
2019-08-20 08:23:31.658 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Starting data transfer.
2019-08-20 08:23:31.658 INFO Ftp(1) Command: TYPE I
2019-08-20 08:23:31.707 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 200 Type set to I.
2019-08-20 08:23:31.709 INFO Ftp(1) Command: PASV
2019-08-20 08:23:31.761 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (198,22,157,51,217,109)
2019-08-20 08:23:31.768 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Establishing data connection to 198.22.157.51:55661.
2019-08-20 08:23:31.821 INFO Ftp(1) Command: RETR /operational_data/ACE/ACE.csv
2019-08-20 08:23:31.880 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for /operational_data/ACE/ACE.csv.
2019-08-20 08:23:32.015 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Data transfer ended. 3528 bytes transferred.
2019-08-20 08:23:32.017 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Closing downloading data connection.
2019-08-20 08:23:32.018 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Waiting for data transfer ending message.
2019-08-20 08:23:32.018 INFO Ftp(1) Response: 226 Transfer complete. 3528 bytes transferred. 3528 bps.
2019-08-20 08:23:32.018 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Data transfer ended.
2019-08-20 08:23:32.018 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Transfer ended successfully.
2019-08-20 08:23:32.018 DEBUG Ftp(1) Info: Data connection closed.
```

Comment: Can you tell us what that specific file is? FTP url?

Comment: From your description it seems that there is some firewall or antivirus software on the server you are running the application on or in your company networks that intercepts the traffic possibly because it finds the name of the file suspicious. (Maybe this is the onle *.exe that you try to download?)

Comment: It's not an .exe file.  It's a text file.  If my local server is intercepting and flagging the traffic, why would I be getting a 550 error from the remote server?  I'll examine our firewall and see if it's set to catch anything.

Comment: Can you verify that you've got the filename/location correct? 550 can indicate file/folder not found. Can also be file permissions, but if they've checked the permissions may it's not that. (did they check permissions?)

Comment: There is firewall software that can intercept connections and then return an error message in the protocol that is used.

Comment: Is it possible that the filename contains characters that are not part of the basic ASCII character set? If yes, this could depend on the character set locale of the client computer.

Comment: The filename only contains valid ASCII characters.  I can download the file occasionally and at other times I get a 550 error.  The location is correct as I have viewed that particular folder from several different applications.

They have checked permissions on the file, and no other users are reporting any issues with downloading the file according to the company that hosts the file.

Comment: Their IT team has raised the idea of "port exhaustion" or a "hung socket".  This doesn't seem possible to me since the 550 error is returned regardless of which machine I am using, as long as it is behind the same outbound IP.  I'm not familiar with the concept of port exhaustion though, so I can't say for certain if their explanation is bunk.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access FTP servers over Fiddler's "HTTP-FTP Gateway". The purpose of this kind of gateways is to make it possible for HTTP clients to access FTP servers. However, Rebex FTP is an FTP client and does not work with HTTP-FTP gateways. The same applies to System.Net.FtpWebRequest. Rebex FTP supports "HTTP CONNECT" proxies, but this is a different kind of proxy than "HTTP-FTP gateway"

Comment: Please create a client-side log using Rebex FTP and post it here. Start with a simple console application such as this (tweak the settings and credentials to suit the server configuration):
 using (var ftp = new Ftp())
 {
  ftp.LogWriter = new ConsoleLogWriter(LogLevel.Debug);
  ftp.Connect("pubftp.spp.org", SslMode.None);
  ftp.Login("username", "password");
  ftp.GetFile("/operational_data/ACE/ACE.csv", Stream.Null);
 }

Comment: @LukasPokorny I took the Fiddle capture when using chrome, not when using the Rebex or System.Net FTP implementations.  

Currently I have rebooted our local server and can download the file.  I will update when it starts failing again, but it might be months, so I'll have to handle that situation when it arises.  I have appended my post with a successful log file in the hopes that it contains some information that might be helpful.